# non-EU citizen with Norway Resident Permit to Visit UK

Tags: visas

A friend of mine asking me to check whether she can travel to UK with Norway Resident permit without applying for entry visa. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A visa is necessary unless she holds a nationality that doesn't require a visa. Her Norwegian residence permit will have no effect.

Comment: This is true unless the Norwegian document is a residence card of a family member of an EU citizen and the friend is traveling to the UK with (or to join) the EU citizen.

Comment: Your friend can check if she needs a visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa